# Upload and convert most common image types to png for fabric canvas background image

Tags: php, jquery, fabricjs

I'm trying to get this image uploading and converting script working correctly.
I had the script uploading any of the valid images and renaming them fine but then I added the conversion code and I can't get it working correctly. I commented out the // imagepng($image); because that caused the success div to fill with �PNG  IHDR��G,�} IDATx���i���u'�s�]�%....... I've worked on this for two days looking at a lot of posts on Stack and thought I understood what was needed. If somebody could please look at this and maybe shed some light on my issue I would greatly appreciate it. In the current configuration I receive no errors on the server. Thanks!

**PHP**

```
 <?php
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/session.php';

     // Detect the file params according to need
 $filename = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
 $filesize = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
 $tmp_name = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
 $custnum = $session->custnum; //Users account number from session

// Valid extensions for Upload
    $validExtensions = array('.jpeg', '.jpg', '.gif', '.png');

// Valid size in KB
  $max_size = 6000;

  // Detect file extension
    $extension = strtolower(strrchr($filename, "."));

      // Convert filesize in KB
       $getFileSize = round($filesize / 1024, 1);

         //Make the storage directory
           if (!file_exists("maps/accounts/".$custnum)) {
          mkdir("maps/accounts/".$custnum, 0777, true);
           }

            // Location to store the file
         $path = str_replace('\/\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)) . "/maps/accounts/".$custnum;

if( in_array($extension, $validExtensions) ){

 if( $getFileSize < $max_size ){

     if(is_dir($path)){

        //***********Start of image conversion***********

         $srcFile = $tmp_name;

list($width_orig, $height_orig, $type) = getimagesize($srcFile);        

// Get the aspect ratio
$ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig;

//Set max size
$width  = 900; 
$height = 600;

// resize to height (orig is portrait) 
if ($ratio_orig < 1) {
    $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
} 
// resize to width (orig is landscape)
else {
    $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
}

// Temporarily increase the memory limit to allow for larger images
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M'); 

switch ($type) 
{
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF: 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($srcFile); 
        break;   
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:  
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcFile); 
        break;   
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:  
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($srcFile);
        break; 
    default:
        throw new Exception('Unrecognized image type ' . $type);
}

         // create a new blank image
   $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

       // Copy the old image to the new image
   imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);  

      imagepng($newImage, $path . '/' . $custnum.'.png');
      imagedestroy($image);
      imagedestroy($newImage);      

        //******End of image conversion****************     



                // Success Message
           echo "<div id='success' class='alert alert-success'><strong>Your map image was uploaded!</strong>
                    <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">&times;</button>
                 </div>";


     } else {
                  trigger_errors("Directory not Found!<br /> $path");
                  }

      } else {
      $error_msg = "<strong>Filesize should be less then $max_size KB!</strong><br />Your file is about $getFileSize KB";
     trigger_errors($error_msg);
  }

    } else {
         $error_msg = "<strong>File not Supproted for Upload!</strong><br />
                Please try with the files that has following extensions: .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png";
      trigger_errors($error_msg);
      }

   // Make function that
  // generate the Error
  function trigger_errors( $error_msg ){
   echo "<div class='alert alert-error'>
     <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">&times;</button>
     $error_msg
     </div>";
   }

   ?>
```

Here's my JQuery Ajax script that is iside the fabric.js kitchensink.js that's calling the above php script.

**JQuery Ajax**

```
$('#loading').hide();
$(function(){
var $form = $('#myform'),
    $result = $('#result');

$('form').on('change','#myfile', function(){
    $('#loading').show();
    $result.ajaxStart(function(){

    }); 

    $form.ajaxForm({
        target: $result

    }).submit();

          $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
               $('#loading').delay(1500).hide('slow');

            if ($('#success').hasClass('alert-success')){    
               canvas.setBackgroundImage(fullurl  , function() {
               canvas.renderAll();
                 });};
          });
});            

})
```

Here's my current html that calls the Ajax and php image processor. This html receives the feed back from the php and ajax success or failure to give feedback to the user.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <form id="myform" action="image_uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table align="center">
          <tr>
              <td width="100"><label>Select File: </label></td>
             <td>
                  <input class="btn shape" type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
<div id="loading"><img src="fabric/img/loadingbar.gif" width="200" height="15" alt="" border="0"><img src="fabric/img/uploading-text.GIF" width="128" height="19" alt="" border="0"></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `move_uploaded_file` actually. In fact, you'll not get the results you want if you do.

```
// create a new blank image
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// Copy the old image to the new image
imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);  

imagepng($newImage, $path . '/' . $custnum);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($newImage);
```

The reason you'll want to do this is that the second argument of [imagepng](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) can be a path to save the file. Since you've gone to all the trouble of converting the file, calling `move_uploaded_file` will move the **original** file into a png filename. So if I upload a JPEG with your script it would move that JPEG into example.png. In other words, it wouldn't be a PNG, it would still be a JPEG.

The reason it's dumping the way you're written is that, without that path, the function returns the raw image so your browser is trying to interpret that binary data as text and, thus, you get gibberish and random characters.

Comment: Dude! That worked. Thank you very much. I will append my code so others will be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are just moving the uploaded file..

So.. Remove this line..

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```